# How to cancel my Pro plan of quickblox?

Tags: quickblox

I have to cancel my pro plan of quickblox.By mistake i have put application id instead of account id.Can anyone suggest me how to cancel my quickblox plan. I am new to quickblox.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Turn to support of quickblox